# problems with the result of np.dot in multiplying matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, sparse-matrix, algebra

I have some problem with matrix multiplication with `np.dot`.

I am multiplying two matrices defined as follows:

```
A = np.diagflat(diag)
```

where diag is an array of random numbers, and `B` which is simply a symmetric matrix. `A` and `B` are both *100 x 100*.

When I try to do `A.dot(B)` I obtain the following result:

```
array([[<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
   [<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
   [<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
   ...,
   [<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
   [<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>],
   [<100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    ...,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>,
    <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
with 460 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>]], dtype=object)
```

I do not understand this result, it seems to be an array of sparse matrices, but why is that? Where am i wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: the correct usage is np.dot(A, B)

Comment: That is irrelevant, `A.dot(B) = np.dot(A, B)`

Comment: I obtain the same result using dot like that :(

Comment: You should consider refactoring the question in a way to include the nature of `B`, including considering editing the title, so that in the future people may find this question.

Comment: The problem is the `np.dot` is using the wrong way of converting `B` to a dense array.  `np.array(B)` produces the about result; `B,toarray()` is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have said that `A` is a diagonal matrix from a random vector:

```
A = np.diagflat(np.random.randint(10, size=100))
```

And `B` is a laplacian of a matrix associate to a graph:

```
R = nx.grid_graph(dim=[10,10])
B = nx.laplacian_matrix(R)
```

The matrix `B` is a [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) and it needs to be converted to a numpy array if you desire to *see* it as such, like for debugging, but if your code needs to scale you should keep it as sparse.

Then the `np.dot` product is:

```
product = A.dot(B.toarray())
```

You can also go with the `B.A` notation, I though it was confusion in this situation:

```
product = A.dot(B.A)
```

With `product` being:

```
array([[16, -8,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [-3,  9, -3, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0, -1,  3, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   ...,
   [ 0,  0,  0, ..., 27, -9,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
   [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0, -4,  8]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I am sorry I didn't specify how i created B: i am studying a graph, so i create a graph using the networkx library as 

R = nx.grid_graph(dim=[10,10]) 

then i obtain matrix B as it's laplacian: 

B = nx.laplacian_matrix(R)

where the laplacian matrix is a semi-definite positive and symmetric matrix

Comment: Ooooh! Thank you! Perfect, now I understand!